# Does Apache Drill support Transaction?

Tags: apache-drill

I haven't seen any reference to the 'Transaction Management' in Drill's documentation. Does Apache Drill support transactions ? Can somebody throw light on this ?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't mention transactions because Drill is a query engine, not a database. I don't think a query engine can control the underlying data sources to do things implied by transaction support, such as rollback.

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-commits/201504.mbox/%3C57582ed040584535b6c5b56def56b82a@git.apache.org%3E

Comment: Looks like there are some things but not full support so I do not believe it supports transactions. That would be weird because, while you can create a TABLE, it is mostly done in a file system so things like ROLLBACK are a bit difficult. You can CREATE and DROP though.